# Counting states

Tags: quantum-spin, quantum-states

Assume we have 6 particles, 3 with spin $\frac{1}{2}$ and another 3 with spin 1. The particles are distinguishable. The energy of a spin s is $\epsilon=-s \mu H$. How many *energy* states the system have? 
Is there an easy way to count? I tried to write all the possible states and it's too much..
For example:
if $s_1=-1$ $s_2=-1$ $s_3=0$ $s_4=\frac{1}{2}$ $s_5=-\frac{1}{2}$ $s_6=\frac{1}{2}$ then the systems energy is $\epsilon=\frac{3}{2}\mu H$ but it is the same as $s_1=0$ $s_2=-1$ $s_3=-1$ $s_4=\frac{1}{2}$ $s_5=\frac{1}{2}$ $s_6=-\frac{1}{2}$ so I don't know how to eliminate the states that are equal.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of counting all possible permutations of the spin configuration you could try this:

1.) what is the maximal energy that the system can have? 
2.) what is the minimal energy?
3.) what is the "energy step", $\Delta E$, that can be realised in this situation?

The highest/lowest energy states are the ones were all spins are aligned. If you flip one spin $1/2$ particle, you will lower the energy by $\Delta E = \mu H/2$. How many of those steps fit into your interval of highest minus lowest energy?